# Session variables not passing to other pages

Tags: php, session-variables

I have a site on my localhost that i am using session variables on.

This is the first page where I defined the session variable for the username:
Newcust.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>

<?php

$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bms");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    printf("Connection Failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_errno());
    exit();
}

else

$_Session ['uname'] = $_POST['uname'];
$pword = $_POST['pword'];
$enc = sha1($pword);
```

echoing the session variable back on the same page returns the correct username. When I try to use the $_Session ['uname'] variable on the next page of the site, it does not register at all.

insert customer.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
echo "hello " .$_Session ['uname'];
?>
```

Could this be a server issue? I am running Apache on my macbook and haven't had a problem with php yet.

Comment: try like this --- $_SESSION['uname']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `$_SESSION`, you have `$_Session` which is incorrect

Comment: Wow, now I just feel like an idiot. Thank you, that solved it.